# UIAlertView lags, leaves dim effect, then causes the screen to flicker on iOS 6.1.3

Tags: objective-c, ios6.1

I have one question related to screen flickering in `iOS 6.1.3`. When I dismiss the `UIAlertView` (When I press OK button of `UIAlertView` in my App) the App gives Dim effect and then flickering starts. It always works same as soon as `UIAlertView` `Ok` button pressed.

But when I leave the app stable for some time the flickering automatically stops or when I change the orientation mode i.e. from landscape to Portrait then again to Landscape the flickering stops.

I got the solution for same problem in `iOS6.1.2.` But that solution does not work for `iOS6.1.3`.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you're displaying that UIAlertView from a background thread - that's never officially been supported, but it didn't start actually causing problems until iOS 6.1.3. Anyway, just launch the UIAlertView from the main thread (`performSelectorOnMainThread:`) and it should work fine.

Comment: I did the same solution (performSelectorOnMainThread:) and it works fine with iOS6.1.2 but (performSelectorOnMainThread:) is not working for iOS 6.1.3....Please advise

Comment: Are you creating the UIAlertView on the main thread too, or only `show:` ing it? The whole thing has to be done on the main thread - create a method to create / show the alert, then call `performSelectorOnMainThread` to perform it all.

Answer (score 2):

This will resolve the problem, just Launch the UIAlertView from the main thread using dispatch_async.

eg.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Internet Status",nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"here is your message",nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil) otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];

        [alt show];
        });
```